# How can I deal with operation between Int and CGFloat?

Tags: objective-c, swift

In Objective-C I can do the following operation:

#### Objective-C code:

```
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(mView.bounds);
CGFloat total = width*[myArray count];
```

but in Swift, it will raise an error:

> Could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied arguments

How can I avoid this situation elegantly?

Comment: Please can you post the actual Swift code you are trying to use?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, let's create some demo data

```
let array: NSArray = ["a", "b", "c"] //you could use a Swift array, too
let view = UIView() //just some view
```

Now, everything else works almost the same way as in Obj-C

```
let width: CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds)
```

or simply

```
let width = CGRectGetWidth(rect) //type of the variable is inferred
```

and total:

```
let total = width * CGFloat(array.count)
```

Note that we have to add a `CGFloat` cast for `array.count`. Obj-C would implicitly cast `NSUInteger` to `CGFloat` but Swift has no implicit casts, so we have to add an explicit one.

Answer (score 8):

In Swift you cannot multiply two numbers of different types (NSNumber, Int, Double, etc.) directly. The width of a CGRect is of floating point type and the array count is of integer type. Here's a working example:

```
let myArray: Int[] = [1,2,3]
let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:100,height:100)
let total: Double = rect.size.width * Double(myArray.count)
```

Comment: Using `NSNumber` to store a `CGFloat` makes me think that you don't really understand what's going on there.

Comment: Good answer to the initial question.

Answer (score 3):

Swift does not allow operations between two numbers of different types. Therefore, before to multiply your `array.count` (`Int`) by your width (`CGFloat`), you'll have to cast it to `CGFloat`.

Fortunately, Swift provides a simple `CGFloat` initializer [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat/3126526-init) that creates a new `CGFloat` from an `Int`. This initializer has the following declaration:

```
init<Source>(_ value: Source) where Source : BinaryInteger
```

> Creates a new value, rounded to the closest possible representation.

---

The Swift 5 Playground sample code below shows how to perform your calculation by using `CGFloat`'s initializer:

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

// Set array and view
let array = Array(1...3)
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let view = UIView(frame: rect)

// Perform operation
let width = view.bounds.width
let total = width * CGFloat(array.count)
print(total) // prints: 300.0
```

Answer (score 0):

need to change All Int to CGFloat Type, or change All CGFloat to Int

```
let a: CGFloat = 0.25
let b: Int = 1
// wrong: Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGFloat' and 'Int'
// let c = a * b
// right: change All Int to CGFloat Type
let r = a * CGFloat(b)
// right: change All CGFloat to Int 
let r = Int(a) * b
```